# Running Mountain Lion cooler

Tags: display, cooling, osx-mountain-lion

I want to run my Mountain Lion as cool as possible. What settings I need to lower the burden over CPU and Display?

My Machine is getting heated too much. I just use my ML for browsing and some text editing, not sure why its heating up too much. Also What display settings I need to run my machine as cooler as possible?

Comment: Machines run fine at a hotter temperature than you think.

Comment: What makes you think it's heating up too much?  Have you cleaned all dust and dirt out of your computer?  May I suggest you edit your question and tell us what kind of hardware your Mountain Lion is running on?

Answer (score 2):

1. Get a simple laptop stand. It doesn't even need a cooler, just get one that lifts it up in mid-air a bit. (Though, a cooler would help more. I have a CoolerMaster E1. It's not that silent, but it keeps my laptop cool, even after hours of 100% load.)
2. You can underclock your CPU. I don't know about the tools on OS X, but that's one way to keep it cool.
3. You can underclock your GPU, if it's a powerful/discrete one. If your machine comes with an Intel integrated GPU, just leave it. It's power-efficient enough.

That's all I can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Install a flash blocker in your browser.  "simple browsing" turns into a CPU nightmare when you visit web sites with flash ads.

For Firefox, FlashBlock:  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/

For Chrome, go to settings, advanced settings, privacy, content settings.  scroll down to Plug-ins and select "click to play" (note, will disable other browser plugins too)

For Safari, ClickToFlash: http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/